# Tikz positioning inside matrix node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have created a figure for tikz that looks like this:

[image]

But when I add it inside a matrix node it became like this:

[image]

Why does this happen?

My code for the first is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[](users){\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{icons/user.png} };
\node[below of=users,yshift=-20](google){\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{icons/googleplus.png} };
\node[below left of=users,yshift=-10](facebook){\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{icons/facebook.png} };
\node[below right of=users,yshift=-10](twitter){\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{icons/tweets.png} };
\draw[->,line width=1] (users)--(facebook);
\draw[->,line width=1] (users)--(google);
\draw[->,line width=1] (users)--(twitter);
\node[below of=google,yshift=8]{Content};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My code for the second is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=red, fill=blue!20, very thick,rectangle, rounded corners,minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=3cm]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=red, text=white,rounded corners]
\node [matrix,mybox] (data){
\node[minimum size=2cm]{};
\node[](users){\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{icons/user.png} };
\node[below of=users,yshift=-20](google){\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{icons/googleplus.png} };
\node[below left of=users,yshift=-10](facebook){\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{icons/facebook.png} };
\node[below right of=users,yshift=-10](twitter){\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{icons/tweets.png} };
\draw[->,line width=1] (users)--(facebook);
\draw[->,line width=1] (users)--(google);
\draw[->,line width=1] (users)--(twitter);
\node[below of=google,yshift=8]{Content};
\\
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (data.north west) {Data};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Do you really need to place `\node`s inside `\node`s? If you are only trying to box the first diagrams, this can be done in different, more appropriate ways.

Comment: Could you please give me some info related to this? I used node inside node just for the box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next code shows how to draw this diagram with a `matrix`.

If you use a `matrix` don't need to use `positioning`, all nodes are adjusted according to rows and columns with certain `column sep` and `row sep`. In this case `default` column and row separation is used, except between first and second row where a particular separation has been fixed with `\\[1cm]`.

A `matrix` is also a `node`, therefore all options applied to `matrix` node are also applied to inner nodes. So `minimum width` and `minimum height` in `mybox` fixes minimum width and height of inner nodes. We can change it with `nodes={...}` at the end of matrix options declaration. In any case I think it's better not using `minimum width/height` in matrix options because the matrix will be big enough to encompass all inner nodes.

`Contents` text below google icon has been drawn as a `label` instead of a regular node.

I've changed icons so, adjust them to your taste.

I've also changed `tikzstyle` to `tikzset`. Please look at [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)

I've used a `matrix` because OP did it. There exist some other solutions to get similar results: Place icons and surround them with `fit` library help, draw inner figure inside a `tcolorbox` or `mdframe`, ...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix}

\tikzset{mybox/.style={draw=red, fill=blue!20, very thick,
            rectangle, rounded corners,
            minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=3cm},
    fancytitle/.style={fill=red, text=white,rounded corners}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [matrix,mybox, nodes={minimum height=0pt}] (data){
& 
\node[](users){\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{user} }; & \\[1cm]

\node[](facebook){\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{facebook} }; & & 
\node[](twitter){\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{tweeter} };
\\
& \node[label=below:Content](google){\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{google+} }; \\
};
\draw[->,line width=1] (users)--(facebook);
\draw[->,line width=1] (users)--(google);
\draw[->,line width=1] (users)--(twitter);
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (data.north west) {Data};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**2nd version:** No matrix but `positioning` and background `fit` node:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (users){\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{user}}; 

\node[below left = 1cm and 1mm of users](facebook){\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{facebook} }; 
\node[below right = 1cm and 1mm of users](twitter){\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{tweeter} };
\node[label={[name=label]below:Content}, below=18mm of users](google){\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{google+} };

\draw[->,line width=1] (users)--(facebook);
\draw[->,line width=1] (users)--(google);
\draw[->,line width=1] (users)--(twitter);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[fit={(users) (twitter) (label) (facebook)}, draw=red, fill=blue!20, very thick, rounded corners, append after command={node[fancytitle, anchor=west] at ([xshift=3mm]\tikzlastnode.north west) {Data}}] {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```